# Is it bad to use bootstrap in a Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

Most "regular" websites I've seen generally use Twitter Bootstrap, at least for the grid layout.

Most themes I've seen to WordPress does **not** use Bootstrap, they are often built with a custom grid layout.

Is Wordpress + bootstrap a bad solution? Or why do so few Wordpress themes use bootstrap?

Comment: There's a tonne of bad assumptions in this question, but ultimately it's just an opinion based question so is off topic anyway.

Comment: It's opinion based and as David says, there's a lot of blog posts with peoples opinions across the web. The main problem people seem to highlight with WP + BS is that you have to add additional code to your theme (such as menu walkers) to integrate BS menus. In some ways BS saves time, but if you've got to write additional code to get it working with WP that time saving is somewhat lost. It's a personal decision as to where you want to save time, write a bunch of integration classes for BS, or write your own CSS classes.

Comment: To extend on my comment above, there are classes available which you can use (with free licenses) to integrate BS with WP. A custom menu walker for example: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with most of the comments, but I'd argue that this is NOT an opinion based question. There's nothing empirically WRONG or BAD about using Bootstrap in WordPress themes. In fact, I do it every single work day. Sage theme is a popular starter theme that uses Bootstrap, and there's plenty others that do as well.

The technologies are perfectly compatible, it's ultimately just up to your design / development goals for the theme. If you desire finer control and don't want to do a bunch of style overrides for a very specific look-and-feel, then maybe Bootstrap isn't right for that particular project. However, there's nothing from the WordPress side of things that would make this a bad solution.

Comment: "it's ultimately just up to your design / development goals for the theme..." Which is subjective and therefore an opinion. There are many, much better SO questions to spend your time on.